# Can a newbie comment on answers to their own questions?

Tags: support, comments, new-users

[This new member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45111592/1440565) seems to think not. It has been a long time since I have been there and I am having difficulty finding clarification on this.

I read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment which does not seem clear to me on this issue. The following paragraph seems the most relevant:

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.

What does "any part of your question" mean? How does one comment on just "part" of a question? Comments are posted below the entire question. Is this referring to answers to your own question? Also, do answers to your own question qualify as "other people's posts"? If the answer to both of these questions is "yes", then the help is contradictory.

Comment: [Second paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @NathanTuggy What does "any part of your questions" mean? And how does that jive with the restriction that "commenting on other people's posts is a privilege."

Comment: Any part. Any post. Any anything on any of your question pages. And that "jives" very simply: commenting on *other people's questions*, or answers to them, is the privilege.

Answer (score 7):

> What does "any part of your questions" mean?

It means that anywhere on a question page a new user sees "add a comment", commenting is available to them, as long as the question is theirs.